# What is the best way of giving my customer the opportunity to edit the content of his website (React) by himself?

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, single-page-application, editing

1. I am creating a website for a customer who wants to be able to make content changes to it by himself: editing text and pictures over time.
2. I don´t want to develop with wordpress or other CMS but still give him the opportunity to visually edit the site without coding knowledge.

Is there a way of integrating some sort of interface to enable this?

I did some research but did not quite find a good way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may load the data from a   `json` file and ask them to edit that file. You may create a google sheets and fetch data from it by a Google Script Apps. Alternatively, you can employ   a headless CMS or write a small backend application by `nodejs`, `python` or `php` to store and fetch content. Still another option is using a cloud backend service  such as `firebase` or `supabase`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! These are interesting approaches to my problem. Which of the solutions would you use to keep it stupid simple :) ?

Comment: @ Ross_O perhaps Google sheets is the simplest option. I haven't tried supabase but that's probably a good option as well. Php offers you easy deployment and probably you can find a 'stupid simple' php backend on github.